# flatMap() in RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm just starting out with RxJava and trying a sample project.

What I'm trying to achieve is

-> Get an object -> 
which contains a list of sub-objects -> Check if the sub-list satisfies a predicate condition -> and emit the sub-objects if satisfies

This is my POJO

```
public class UpComingMovies {

@SerializedName("results")
  private List<Movies> results;
}

public class Movies {

@SerializedName("overview")
  private String overview;

@SerializedName("original_language")
  private String originalLanguage;
}
```

So, from what I understand is that I can use `flatMap` and transform the item to multiple observables and then use `filter` saying give me movies which has `originalLanguage.equals("en")`

This is what I have tried to do

```
 @GET("movie/upcoming")
Observable<UpComingMovies> getUpComingMovies(@Query("api_key") String apiKey, @Query("page") String page);

private final CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    disposables.add(RetrofitConnection.getService()
            .getUpComingMovies(Config.API_KEY, "1")
            .flatMapIterable(new Function<UpComingMovies, Iterable<Movies>>() {
                @Override
                public Iterable<Movies> apply(@NonNull UpComingMovies upComingMovies) throws Exception {
                    // does not compile - needs an iterable
                    return upComingMovies.getResults().iterator();
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<UpComingMovies>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(UpComingMovies upComingMovies) {
                    Log.d(getClass().getName(), upComingMovies.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.d(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onComplete");
                }
            }));
}
```

However, it does not compile. 
Cleary I do not know how to do this, any help is appreciated

Comment: You just need to `return upComingMovies.getResults().iterator()`, no?

Comment: Needs Iterable not iterator, another way might be to use map and transform to movies and add filter there? Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Similar idea. Just return the result list

Comment: `getResults()` is a `List`. `List` is an `Iterable`.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter shouldn't compile because of the previous function that generates an iterable of UpcomingMovies. In other words, that filter is expecting an observable of movies, but the previous function is mapping to an iterable of UpcomingMovies

You seem to be wanting to map UpcomingMovies into a List / Iterable of **Movies**

In order to do that, try starting with this Function definition

```
flatMapIterable(new Function<UpComingMovies, Iterable<Movies>>()
```

Then, you can use `getResults()` of the UpcomingMovies object parameter, to get the sublist, return it, then that's passed to the subsequent filter operation

In code,

```
.flatMapIterable(new Function<UpComingMovies, Iterable<Movies>>() {
    @Override
    public Iterable<Movies> call(UpComingMovies upcomingMovies) {
        return upcomingMovies.getResults();
    }
})
```

Also, if you enable Java 8 compilation with lambdas, then the code is much simpler... Reduced to one line

```
.flatMapIterable(UpComingMovies::getResults)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this, I seem not to understand this

Comment: Replace `Iterable<UpComingMovies>` with `Iterable<Movies>`

Comment: Like I said, just return the list. Any collection is an iterable, not iterators

Comment: @cricket_007 `flatMapIterable` is precisely there to avoid having to create explicitely Observables from Iterables. Instead, the `getResult()` can be used directly

Comment: Definitely exists. https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables Maybe I'm conflicting RxJava1

Comment: I'm using RxJava2

Comment: @njzk2 Like that?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, that's what I was referring to